# How did Cassini desaturate the momentum wheels without +Z axis thrusters? (limited pitch or yaw)

Tags: cassini

Re: Cassini’s thruster axis

Without +Z and corresponding -Z thrusters firing, it appears yaw or pitch authority would be very limited.

Information on the quads is difficult to find. Is this attached image misleading?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: None of the single thrusters point through the center of mass(nor through the axis), they are intended to be used in pairs. With a mismatch between the pair, rotation about any axis is achieved.

Comment: Is the Z axis marked in the picture ? Is the Z axis, in the "vertical" direction ? Can you add a credit to the image posted in the question ? Is a higher resolution version available for viewing ?